# Python ibm_db List in the Where Clause

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, db2

I'm using Python to read in a csv file of names and then incorporate those names into a sql query. Using ibm_sql, I'm trying to place the list variable in a sql `WHERE` clause: `WHERE IN (List)`

How would I go about referencing the list `sample` in the `WHERE` clause?: `WHERE a.name IN (sample)`

```
#pip install ibm-db
import ibm_db_dbi as db

conn = db.connect("DATABASE=xxx;HOSTNAME=xxx;PORT=xxx;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx;", "", "")
with open('file.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None) #skip header
    data = list(reader) #list
    sample = data[:20]

#sql
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = '''
SELECT name
FROM (

SELECT DISTINCT a.name, b.number
FROM table1 as a
JOIN table2 as b ON a.sk = b.sk
WHERE a.name IN _____________ <<<
order by b.number
)
group by name
'''
 #{}.format(sample)
cursor.execute(sql)

for r in cursor.fetchall():
    print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider interpolating a comma-separated list of qmarks, `?` (equal to your number of items in list). Then, pass your list as parameters in `execute` call:

```
sql = '''SELECT name
         FROM (
             SELECT DISTINCT a.name, b.number
             FROM table1 as a
             JOIN table2 as b ON a.sk = b.sk
             WHERE a.name IN ({})
             ORDER BY b.number
         ) sub
         GROUP BY name
      '''

qmarks = ", ".join(['?' for i in sample])

cursor.execute(sql.format(qmarks), sample)

for r in cursor.fetchall():
    print(r)
```